# Can I pipe a io.BytesIO() stream to subprocess.popen() in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, bytesio

I'm trying to **pipe** a **io.BytesIO()** bytetream to a separate program using **subprocess.popen()**, but I don't know how or if this is at all possible. Documentation and examples are all about text and newlines.

When I whip up something like this:

```
import io
from subprocess import *

stream = io.BytesIO()
someStreamCreatingProcess(stream)

command = ['somecommand', 'some', 'arguments']  
process = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE)
process.communicate(input=stream)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    procOut         = process.communicate(input=stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 754, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1322, in _communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1384, in _communicate_with_poll
    chunk = input[input_offset : input_offset + _PIPE_BUF]
TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I think **popen()** is only for text. Am I wrong?
Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [@falsetru said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321129/4279) you can't stream `BytesIO()` object directly; you need to get a bytestring from it first. It implies that all content should be already written to `stream` *before* you call `stream.getvalue()` to pass to `process.communicate()`.

If you want to *stream* instead of providing all input at once then you could drop `BytesIO()` object and write to the pipe directly:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['command', 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
someStreamCreatingProcess(stream=process.stdin) # many `stream.write()` inside
process.stdin.close() # done (no more input)
process.wait()
```

`someStreamCreatingProcess()` should not return until it is done writing to the stream. If it returns immediately then it should call `stream.close()` at some point in the future (remove `process.stdin.close()` in your code):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['command', 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
someStreamCreatingProcess(stream=process.stdin) # many `stream.write()` inside
process.wait() # stream.close() is called in `someStreamCreatingProcess`
```

Comment: Uptvoted. What do you mean 'should not'? Should not in general, or will not after using this code? Normally `someStreamCreatingProcess()` returns immediately but keeps streaming until it explicitly receives the command to stop streaming (video in this case).

Comment: @Redsandro: I've shown how to handle case when `someStreamCreatingProcess()` returns immediately.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks, I will give this a go when I'm back.

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm back, and I accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

According to [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> The optional input argument **should be a string** to be sent to the child
>   process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

---

To get (bytes) string value from `BytesIO` object, use [`getvalue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue):

```
process.communicate(input=stream.getvalue())
```

Comment: _N.B._ In python a string is a group of _bytes_, which may, or may not, be interpreted as text by the code and the libraries depending on the context.  It took me a little while to realise this myself.

Comment: Although this answer resolves the error message, the resulting pipe data is not accepted by e.g. `ffmpeg` _pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input._ When writing the stream directly to a file first, the file _is_ accepted by `ffmpeg`. I think @SteveBarnes is on to something that's also relevant in this case.

Comment: Try using `io.BufferedReader` as buffing is always recommended for binary data.

Comment: It may be a good idea to add `universal_newlines=False, bufsize=-1` to your POpen call to ensure that newline chars are not being mangled and the correct buffering is used.  I also think that you may have to do something about closing file descriptors.

Comment: @Redsandro, Does `stream` contain all data when you call `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: @SteveBarnes: `bufsize` doesn't affect correctness -- whether ffmpeg works or not -- only its time performance in this case. `universal_newlines` *is* `False` by default; you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @falsetru, Nope, `stream` is being streamed into for an undetermined period of time by `someStreamCreatingProcess(stream)`. Isn't that how this works?

Comment: @Redsandro, Then, J.F. Sebastian's answer is what you want.

Comment: I found some comments about some python versions defaulting `universal_newlines` to `True` and adding a unnecessary parameter that matches the default is not usually a problem.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, Which version? [2.4](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node235.html), [2.5](http://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/node528.html), [2.6](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [3.1](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [3.2](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), [3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)