# How do I copy a PIL picture to clipboard

Tags: python, bash, tkinter, xclip

I'm working with a canvas in Tkinter, and I'm trying to copy the contents of that canvas to the clipboard.

I am able to solve this by creating a file, and then copy the content of that file into the clipboard with `xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i temp_file.png`, but I want to use a buffer instead, allowing the user to copy it directly to the clipboard without touching the filesystem of the user.

To use `xclip`'s input function, I require to give a filename, and not a string.
I can circumvent this with echo/cat as `cat temp_file.png < echo | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i` or `cat file_name.png | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i` in the bash-line.

I have successfully been able to use the buffer to store the canvas, as such:

```py
memory = io.BytesIO()
img.save(memory, format="png")
return memory
```

and can save the picture to a file as this:

```
img = pil.Image.open(memory)
img.save("file_name.png", format="png")
```

As far as I have understood, from pil's documentation, `pil.Image.open` is the same as the built-in `open()` function. Nevertheless, when trying to use open() to read the file, it claims BytesIO is not a valid file. Not a major problem, I guess.

I can read the contents of the buffer with `memory.getvalue()`, and then strip the surrouding `b'...'` with [2:-1]. I then replace all the `'` in the string with `\'`, so I can surround it with single quotation marks, and end up echoing said string with the command I used on a file earlier.

```
img_data = str(img_memory.getvalue())[2:-1]
img_data = img_data.replace("'", "\'")#.replace("`", "\`")
img_data = "'" + img_data + "'"
```

The output of `cat file_name.png` is pretty much the same as the output of the string I'm giving `echo` in my subprocess, but the following doesn't seem to do the job for me, as my clipboard remains untouched:

```py
bash_cmd = f"echo -n {img_data} | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i"
p = sp.Popen(bash_cmd, shell=True, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

but

```py
bash_cmd = f"xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i file_name.png"
p = sp.Popen(bash_cmd, shell=True, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

does work.

## tl;dr

What am I doing wrong? Am I altering the contents of the file, and creating a corrupt image, which is then copied?

How can I properly output the contents of a `io.BufferIO` into my clipboard (mainly on Unix/Linux, but also on MacOS/Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to copy the image data with xclip from python by adapting the answer from [Can I pipe a io.BytesIO() stream to subprocess.popen() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321116/can-i-pipe-a-io-bytesio-stream-to-subprocess-popen-in-python/20322468#20322468). No need to use `echo` here, but just write the content of `memory` to the process stdin:

```py
memory = io.BytesIO()
img.save(memory, format="png")

output = subprocess.Popen(("xclip", "-selection", "clipboard", "-t", "image/png", "-i"), 
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# write image to stdin
output.stdin.write(memory.getvalue())
output.stdin.close()
```

As for a more multi-platform solution, I found the package [klembord](https://pypi.org/project/klembord/) which works on Linux and Windows. The following command copies the picture to the clipboard (tested in Linux only):

```py
import klembord
klembord.set({"image/png": memory.getvalue()})
```