# Is there a way to calculate the output frame dimensions when compressing a video and extracting its frames with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I use the following code to compress a video and extract its frames. Note that I do not want to save the resulting video.

```
        output_args = {
            "vcodec": "libx265",
            "crf": 24,
        }
        out, err = (
            ffmpeg
            .input(in_filename)
            .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24',**output_args)
            .run(capture_stdout=True)
        )
        frames = np.frombuffer(out, np.uint8).reshape(-1,width,height,3)
```

When i try to reshape the output buffer to original video dimensions I get the following error:
`cannot reshape array of size 436567 into shape (1920,1080,3)`
This is expected because the resulting video has smaller dimensions. Is there a way to calculate the number of frames, width, and height of the compressed video in order to reshape the frames from the buffer?

Also, if I save the compressed video, instead of loading its frames, and then I load the video frames from the compressed video, these would have the same dimensions as the original. I suspect that there is some sort of interpolation happening under the hood. Is there a way to apply it without saving the video?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

Assumptions:

- `out` holds the entire h265 encoded stream in memory buffer.
- You don't want to write the stream into a file.

The solution applies the following:

- Execute `FFmpeg` in a sub-process with `sdtin` as input `pipe` and `stdout` as output `pipe`.
  The input is going to be the video stream (memory buffer).
  The output format is raw video frames in BGR pixel format.
- Write stream content to the `pipe` (to `stdin`).
- Read decoded video (frame by frame), and display each frame (using `cv2.imshow`)

For testing the solution, I created a sample video file, and read it into memory buffer (encoded as H.265).
I used the memory buffer as input to the above code (your `out` buffer).

Here is the complete code, include the testing code:

```
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import cv2
import io

in_filename = 'in.mp4'

# Build synthetic video, for testing begins:
###############################################
# ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -c:v libx265 -crf 24 -t 5 in.mp4

width, height = 192, 108

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('testsrc=size={}x{}:rate=1'.format(width, height), r=10, f='lavfi')
    .output(in_filename, vcodec='libx265', crf=24, t=5)
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
###############################################


# Use ffprobe to get video frames resolution
###############################################
p = ffmpeg.probe(in_filename, select_streams='v');
width = p['streams'][0]['width']
height = p['streams'][0]['height']
n_frames = int(p['streams'][0]['nb_frames'])
###############################################


# Stream the entire video as one large array of bytes
###############################################
# https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md
in_bytes, _ = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename)
    .video # Video only (no audio).
    .output('pipe:', format='hevc', crf=24)
    .run(capture_stdout=True) # Run asynchronous, and stream to stdout
)
###############################################


# Open In-memory binary streams
stream = io.BytesIO(in_bytes)

# Execute FFmpeg in a subprocess with sdtin as input pipe and stdout as output pipe
# The input is going to be the video stream (memory buffer)
# The output format is raw video frames in BGR pixel format.
# https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md
# https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/156
# http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/
process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:', format='hevc')
    .video
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True)
)


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321116/can-i-pipe-a-io-bytesio-stream-to-subprocess-popen-in-python
# https://gist.github.com/waylan/2353749
process.stdin.write(stream.getvalue())  # Write stream content to the pipe
process.stdin.close()  # close stdin (flush and send EOF)


# Read decoded video (frame by frame), and display each frame (using cv2.imshow)
while(True):
    # Read raw video frame from stdout as bytes array.
    in_bytes = process.stdout.read(width * height * 3)

    if not in_bytes:
        break

    # transform the byte read into a numpy array
    in_frame = (
        np
        .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
        .reshape([height, width, 3])
    )

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('in_frame', in_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

process.wait()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: I used `stdin` and `stdout` instead of names pipes because I wanted the code to work both in Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the reason I posted the question is that I want to compress the video first and then load the frames on RAM. So I need to use compression parameters like `vcodec` and `crf`. Are you saying that I cannot get raw RGB  with these parameters?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible. In case it's possible, it's complicated: you need to build a filter graph with two output streams: compressed stream that saves to disk, and uncompressed that goes to pipe. It's much more simple to use two `FFmpeg` commands.

Comment: In case I misunderstand you, and you want compressed sequence in RAM, you **can't** reshape it into frames, because you need to decode it first (for decoding, you can use FFmpeg [complicated], or use OpenCV capture). I don't know if it's going to work with all the (compressed) video stream in the RAM.

Comment: Yes, I want the compressed sequence in RAM. If I save the compressed video in the disk first, then I can extract the compressed frames in RAM using the original video's shape. But my constraint is that don't want to use the disk. I will maybe search if there is a way to decode it first as you suggested.

Comment: I posted a new example that works with compressed sequence in RAM. The code sample does not address your question specifically. With minor modifications, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will check this when I 'll find the time and come back to you. Much appreciated